# How do I can reduce the number of activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, optimization, project, reduce

I have an android project .But it's getting larger and the problem is I need to create activity for every screen .Can I optimize the activities after the completion of the whole project? How can I do that ?

Comment: Simple,Use fragments

Comment: is there any way other than using fragments? @insomniac

Comment: yes @insomniac right you have to use fragment. That can be reduce the number of activity.

Comment: the Other option is to write code in a way that you can re-use activity classes,which i believe is a bad idea for you because there will be loads of conditional statements and it would only make it more complex for you team mates,But if you use fragments it is just some tweaking in current code

Comment: "I need to create activity for every screen" what do you mean by that. Are you showing similar data on each activity or all of your activities are on same pattern ?

Comment: whenever I need to show user some UI I had to create new activity for every screen @penguin

Answer (score 3):

> Can I optimize the activities after the completion of the whole
>   project? How can I do that ?

Use `Fragments` instead of `Activity` whenever possible.

Comment: hmm fragment seems to be the only alternative to activity :(

Answer (score 1):

1)Use Fragment 
**OR**

- Pass unique ID Using Intent from first Activity to Second
  Activity.
- and when you comes to the second Activity check the ID and do
  whatever u want .
- for Example if you pass id =1
- it will check and show toast one,
- -if id =2
- it will check and show toast two

If we have two button in **FirstActivity.**
    button1,button2

- on button1 Click

> Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
>      i.putExtras("ID",1);
>        startActivity(i);

on button2 Click

> Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
>      i.putExtras("ID",2);
>        startActivity(i);

In **Second Activity**

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
           int id = i.getInt("ID");

            }
if(id=1){
Toast 1
 }else if(id=2){
toast 2
}else{
toast 3
}
```

Comment: thnx... I did activity switch in that way.....I did not use fragment at all @Yogesh